# Prove the next inequality (complex)

Tags: complex-analysis

I got this question in my homework: Let
$$0<r<1,\quad D_r=\{z:|z|<r\}.$$

Prove that in $D_r$ the next inequality is valid:
$$\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)\leq\frac{r}{r+1}.$$

Well, I was trying to prove it with the series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-q}$ when $q = \frac{1}{z} $, but without success.

Thanks, for any help.

Comment: How are you trying to work out an expression for the real part of $\frac{z}{z-1}$?

Comment: You'll probably need to do as lux suggested.  Try playing around with $z=re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$-1$ to both sides shows that

It is equivalent to prove

$$Re (\frac {1}{1-z})\ge \frac {1}{r+1}$$
or

$$\frac {1+r^2-2r\cos (t)}{1-r\cos (t)}\le r+1$$

or

$$r^2-r\cos (t)\le r-r^2\cos (t) $$
and
$$r-\cos (t)\le 1-r\cos (t) $$
equivalent to
$$r (1+\cos (t))\le 1+\cos (t) $$
which is true.

Comment: Thank you, you don't refer to the original z/(z-1), because |z| < r?

Comment: $z/(z-1)-1=1/z-1$. with$ z  =re^{it} $

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more work than it first appears.  Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{z}{z-1} & = \frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}-1}=\frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}-1}\cdot\frac{re^{-i\theta}-1}{re^{-i\theta}-1} \\ 
& = \frac{r^2-re^{i\theta}}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1}=\frac{r^2-r\cos{\theta}-ir\sin{\theta}}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the real part
$$\begin{align}
Re\big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big) & = Re\big(\frac{r^2-re^{i\theta}}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1})=\frac{r^2-r\cos{\theta}}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1} \\
&=\frac{r(r-\cos{\theta})}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1}
\end{align}
$$
If we knew that $\dfrac{r-\cos{\theta}}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1}\le\dfrac{r+1}{r^2+2r+1}=\dfrac{1}{r+1}$, we'd be finished.  But I don't think that's obvious.  It is true.  By taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$ and finding the critical values, you can show that the max is at $\theta = \pi$, so 
$$\begin{align}
Re\big(\frac{z}{z-1}\big) & = \frac{r(r-\cos{\theta})}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1} \le 
\dfrac{r(r+1)}{r^2+2r+1}=\dfrac{r}{r+1}
\end{align}
$$
As a check I think the derivative of $\dfrac{r-\cos{\theta}}{r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1}$ should be $\dfrac{\sin{\theta}(1-r^2)}{(r^2-2r\cos{\theta}+1)^2}$ giving critical values of $0$ and $\pi$.

Edit:  Finally to fill a small gap we do need to appeal to $r<1$ in order to decide where the max occurs.  Otherwise the sign of $1-r^2$ in the derivative changes the conclusion.