# Prove that: $Re(\frac{z}{z-1})\le \frac{r}{r+1}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

let $0<r<1$ and $D_r$={${z: |z|<r}$}, prove that inside $D_r$ we get that:

$Re(\frac{z}{z-1})\le \frac{r}{r+1}$

all I could reach is that the real value we need is $\frac{x(x-1)+y^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$, now how can I continue from here?

Comment: See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2299455/254075 and especially this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2299504/254075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here we need to prove that
$$\frac{x^2-x+y^2}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\leq\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1}$$ or
$$(x^2-x+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x^2-x+y^2\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2-2x+1+y^2)$$ or
$$(1-x)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq x^2-x+y^2,$$
which is obvious for $x^2-x+y^2<0$.

But for $x^2-x+y^2\geq0$ we need to prove that
$$(1-x)^2(x^2+y^2)\geq(x^2-x+y^2)^2$$ or
$$y^2(1-x^2-y^2)\geq0,$$
which is true.

Now, since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<r$, we obtain:
$$Re\frac{z}{z-1}\leq\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}<\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{r}}=\frac{r}{r+1}.$$
Done!